# How to count trues and falses in a two column data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

**Here is my code:**

```
pizzarequests = pd.Series(open('pizza_requests.txt').read().splitlines())
line = "unix_timestamp_of_request_utc"
lines = pizzarequests[pizzarequests.str.contains(line)].str.split(",").str[1]
print(lines)
dts = pd.to_datetime(lines, unit='s')
hours = dts.dt.hour
print(hours)


pizzarequests = pd.Series(open('pizza_requests.txt').read().splitlines())
line = "requester_received_pizza"
lines = pizzarequests[pizzarequests.str.contains(line)].str.split(",").str[1]

data = pd.DataFrame({'houroftheday' : hours.values, 'successpizza' : lines})
print(data)
```

****Which gives me:****

```
        houroftheday successpizza
23                18        true 
67                 2        true 
105               14        true 
166               23        true 
258               20        true 
297                1        true 
340                2        true 
385               22        true 
...
304646            21       false 
304686            12       false 
304746             1       false 
304783             3       false 
304840            20       false 
304907            17       false 
304948             1       false 
305023             4       false
```

How can I sum the hours that only correspond to the trues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter all rows by `True`s in column `successpizza` and then `sum` column `houroftheday`:

```
sum_hour = data.loc[data['successpizza'] == 'true', 'houroftheday'].sum()
print (sum_hour)
102
```

If want `size` is necessary only count `True`s, if use `sum`, `True`s are processes like `1`:

```
len_hour = (data['successpizza'] == 'true').sum()
print (len_hour)
8
```

Or if need length of each `houroftheday`:

```
mask = (data['successpizza']  == 'true').astype(int)
out = mask.groupby(data['houroftheday']).sum()
print (out)
houroftheday
1     1
2     2
3     0
12    0
14    1
18    1
20    1
21    0
22    1
23    1
Name: successpizza, dtype: int32
```

Solution for remove traling whitespaces is [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
line = "requester_received_pizza"
lines = pizzarequests[pizzarequests.str.contains(line)].str.split(",").str[1].str.strip()
```

Comment: is looks like the `successpizza` is a column of strings with `'true'` and `'false'` as the values.

Comment: When I do the length of each which Is what I need it gives me that every hour has zero counts of true. What could be going wrong?

Comment: If data are not confidenatal, can you send me file `pizza_requests.txt` to my email in my profile? Because it seems some data dependent problem.

Comment: So when I do this line: mask = (data['successpizza']  == 'true').astype(int), it is assigning zeros to all the trues and all the falses in the data frame. Why isn't it assigning a one to the trues?

Comment: I sent the data, let me know. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So problem is traling whitespaces, check it by `print(data['successpizza'].tolist()[:5])`

Comment: And solution was added to answer

Comment: Loads of help! Clicked on the check mark. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a count of the occurrences of each hour where `successpizza` is `true`. If so you will want to slice the data frame using `successpizza`, then `groupby` the `houroftheday` column and aggregate using a count.

It also looks like you are reading in the true/false values from a file, so they are strings.  You will need to convert them first.

```
data.successpizza = data.successpizza.apply(lambda x: x=='true')
data[data.successpizza].groupby('houroftheday').count()
```